# Sending push notification from Gmail API to localhost endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

### What I'm trying to do

I'm using the Gmail API + Google Pub/Sub API to deliver [Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) to my Node server running on an EC2 instance, for every time I receive an email on a `watch()`ed inbox. I add the domain of my server to the Push section of [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com), and then for the Pub/Sub API, I create a subscription and add the Push Endpoint URL. The endpoint looks something like this: `https://example.com/receive`.

What I'd like to do is to test this locally.

### The problem

**How do I make Google send push notifications to my localhost server?** When I test, I'd like notifications for new emails to be sent to `http://localhost:8080/receive`. I was thinking of perhaps using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose localhost - the problem though is that I would have to manually upload a proof for Google (that I own the domain) every time the ngrok URL changed, which is a huge headache.

Does there exist some nicer way of receiving the new email notification on my localhost server?

Comment: can you explain me please how to go forward. I'm trying to subscribe to ebay notifications, do i need to create 2 different application one for subscription may be a console app? and one a listener may be api? I'm doing it using .net mvc c#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to pay $5/month to ngrok and get a custom subdomain. Another option is to emulate HTTP POST requests for those notifications by yourself. It's doable by curl as follows:

```
$ curl -i --data @push_notification.json http://localhost:8080/receive
```

You need to have a local file 'push_notification.json' with the same content as the gmail push notification.

Answer (score 0):

Google's push notification are HTTP**S** POST calls to an endpoint.
For HTTPS to work, a valid SSL certificate that matches a public domain name.  So, you will need the following:

```
1. A public domain name.
2. an SSL certificate that matches that particular domain name. 
3. your domain should be publically reachable on port 443.
```

If you are working in a company, ask the IT department to allocate a domain name to your host, reachable from the internet, with appropriate certificate.

If it is for a home connection, you cannot use a free/noip/etc domain, like the ones that end with *.ddns.net because you cannot get an SSL certificate for .ddns.net. 
But you can get a *.biz or *.info domain name for less than $10 a year.
Also, if you are using a home connection and don't have fixed IP, choose a domain registrar that allows for an automatic IP address updating.

For an SSL certificate, you can get a free 3-month trial from companies like comodo, or a 1-3 year certificate and these can be also very cheap if you use one of the discount resellers. I suggest skipping the 3-month free trial because after three months you are likely to have to do it again anyway and your time is probably worth more than $8.

Since those are standard HTTPS requests, the endpoint should be publically reachable on port 443. For instance, have port 443 open the modem/firewall but route it to a higher port (>1024) so you don't need to run the endpoint server as root (if on linux).

Answer (score 0):

You can you [serveo](http://serveo.net/) to expose your local server to the Internet (ssh) via domain which you own. If you use Linux (one of popular distro) you can do it without installing any additional software:

1. Generate ssh key (`ssh-keygen`)
2. Get key's fingerprint (`ssh-keygen -l`)
3. In domain configuration:

   - Point `A` to `159.89.214.31` (check on the servo page)
   - Add `TXT` record with value `authkeyfp=fingerprint_from_point_2`
4. Tunnel port 8080 from localhost to 80 on your_domain.com: `ssh -R
   your_domain.com:80:localhost:8080 serveo.net`